# making voice overs sounding cartoonish?

Tags: cartoon, voice-over

hello all,

need help on making voice overs sound more cartoonish, i tried the obvious...pitching, but still need something that will give cartoonish feel to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion the only voices that can be made cartooney in post is chipmunks, smurfs, and shrunken people voices, absolutely everything else (that I can think of right now) is a matter of great and talented voice-actors. It doesn't matter if it's Bugs Bunny, Donald Duck, Weebl, Bart Simpsons, Stimpy, Schwartzenegger, or perhaps Itchy and Scratchy, it's all in the mouth, with little or absolutely no processing other than the usual compressor and EQ.

EDIT: One thing that, if done right, can sound very good and cartoony, is ventriloquism! When doing voice-acting visual lipflap doesn't matter of course, but the very technique of ventriloquism often gives a very nice "middy" kind of voice often associated with toons, and much of it's character, as far as I know (can't actually do it myself), is actually based in forming the words in other ways than usual, resulting in somewhat different performances.
This song, performed by the late Shari Lewis as both herself and the puppets, shows my point very well!
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4ztfrr8fls&feature=related

Also, I stick to my opinion that living things needs living voices, but after thinking a little more about it I remembered some inanimate object with voices formed by nice mechanical effects! One is the trains in Disney-movies, for example Dumbo, which is made by placing a kind of more vibrator-esque loudspeaker to the throat and speaking with it playing soundwaves of choice. Reminds a little of vocoders, but way more organic. The other thing is talking springs, for example the one Donald Duck fought in an early short! They're jaw harps, no more, no less :-)

Answer (score 4):

Helium during the actual voiceover recording.  The voiceover talent is pretty much everything, since the delivery speed and cadence can create cartoonish qualities, and that kind of inflection can't be easily "mapped" by DSP.  It's a human nuance.  Or if you do play with pitch, try altering the formant as well (I know Waves UltrPitch allows for this, I'm sure there are many others too) - that can create some strange qualities.  Could also try [Antares THROAT Evo](http://www.antarestech.com/products/avox-evo.shtml#throat)